# jmathplot - rotating axis label misalign line plot

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, plot, jmathplot

i'm using [jmathplot](http://code.google.com/p/jmathplot/) to paint some line plots. Everything works fine for me, but when i'm rotating the axis labels, the plots will be misaligned. I already posted this issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/jmathplot/issues/detail?id=8) but no one answered yet.

Any suggestions?

SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.math.plot.Plot2DPanel;
import org.math.plot.plotObjects.BaseLabel;

public class JMathPlotDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame myWindow = new JFrame("JMathPlotDemo");
        myWindow.setSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        myWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Plot2DPanel myPlot = new Plot2DPanel();
        myPlot.removePlotToolBar();
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
            double[] x = new double[5];
            double[] y = new double[5];
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j ++){
                x[j] = j;
                y[j] = Math.random()*10;
            }
                myPlot.addLinePlot("Line "+(i+1), x, y);
        }

        myPlot.setSize(400, 400);

        myPlot.getAxis(0).setLabelText("My x axis label");
        myPlot.getAxis(0).setLabelPosition(0.5, -0.15);
        myPlot.getAxis(1).setLabelText("My y axis label");
        myPlot.getAxis(1).setLabelAngle(-Math.PI / 2); 
        myPlot.getAxis(1).setLabelPosition(-0.15, 0.5);

        myPlot.addLegend(Plot2DPanel.SOUTH);
        BaseLabel title = new BaseLabel("JMathPlotDemo", Color.black, 0.5, 1.1);
        myPlot.addPlotable(title);
        myWindow.setContentPane(myPlot);
        myWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: problem solved by using JFreeChart

Answer (score 1):

From OP since hasn't been around for a while:

"problem solved by using JFreeChart"